# two column value in a single column using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am getting output in different format, here is my query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(lead_id) AS `leads`,
  Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) AS `Month`
FROM `lead`  
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`));
```

**Output:**

```
Month
312c31
322c31
332c31
342c31
352c31
362c31
372c31
382c31
392c31
31302c31
31312c31
31322c31
```

**Required Output:**

```
month
1,1
2,23
3,4
5,6
6,34
7,76
8,2
9,3
10,5
11,4
12,1
```

Comment: Any One can solve this

Comment: What is the relation of `31302c31` with `10,5` ? Share an example of `created_at` here

Comment: created_at is the date which i saved in epoch time formate

Comment: expected output is month, counts

Comment: because of the count function it ll display like 31302c31

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
  CAST(
      CONCAT(
          MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)), 
          ',',
          COUNT(lead_ID)
      ) AS CHAR
  ) AS 'Month'
FROM lead
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-01-01")) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-12-31"))
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
```

Comment: i need the output in a single column with comma separator like first month 1,number of records,second month 2,number of records example         first row 1,10 second row 2,4 like wise for 12months

Comment: your query is for displaying output in two columns i need to diaplay it in one single column

Answer (score 0):

**i got an answer thankyou for all you replies ur replies also an usefull information here is my query**

```
SELECT
    *,
    concat(leads, ",", month)as leadss 
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(lead_id) as 'leads,
        Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) AS `Month`
    FROM `lead`
    WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
)AS ab
```